# Set three decimal places

Tags: vb.net, decimalformat

I have to plot into a richtextbox some values that are contained into a datagridview. Since these are double-precision numbers, I have to truncate them with three decimal places. I looked around and I tried to do this:

```
 For i = 0 To DataGridView3.Rows.Count - 2
            RichTextBox3.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "K,   " + (i + 1).ToString + ",   " + DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString("F3") + ",   " + DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString("F3") + ",   " + DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString("F3"))
        Next
```

When debugging, I'm receiving this error: `System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "F3" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'`
How could I solve this issue? Thanks all are gonna answer me. Best regards

Comment: Try `CDbl(DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value).ToString("F3")`.

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` to avoid these kind of problems. You would immediately see, while writing your code, that you're trying to use `Object.ToString(index)`. The Cells' values are always of Type `Object`.